# I would like to use regex to create a pattern that matches stems of three words, regardless of their order

Tags: regex

I am using Blackboard to create a test. One of the questions has as the answer: `TIF, PDF, or Native`. Blackboard has the ability to use pattern matching to validate answers for fill-in-the-blank questions.

What regex will accept an answer containing all these words, regardless of the order and ignoring if a student puts an "and" in the answer?

Possible correct answers:

```
TIF PDF Native  
Tifs, Pdfs, and natives  
native and pdf and tif  
pdf, tifs  natives
tifs with text and metadata, PDF, Native
```

I need all three words, but I can ignore extra words.

I will quality control the answers, so if someone submits: `tifs text pdf native excel image hard drive server`, I will catch it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look ahead for each word:

```
^(?i)(?=.*\btifs?\b)(?=.*\bpdfs?\b)(?=.*\bnatives?\b).*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/tODxkSfZIW).

Because look aheads don't consume input, their order and the order of the terms in the input are flexible.

Each term is wrapped in `\b` (word boundary) to ensure they are "words", eg "stiff pdf native" wouldn't match.

`s?` means an optional "s" at the end of the words (to allow plurals)

`(?i)` means "case insensitive".

Comment: This is great! I took off the \b at the end of each term so that plurals are matched. It seems to work.

Comment: @jqning recheck the answer: I added optional "s" at the end of each word. Follow the link to the demo too.